# Retrieve SagaData instance from inside a bus event

Tags: c#, rebus

I´m trying to add an MessageSent event where I want to:

1. View if the message was sent from a saga handler.
2. If we are inside a saga, access to the corresponding SagaData instance.

For the first point, I know that I have to check if the MessageContext has an item with the key "SagaContextItemKey", but I am quite lost at getting the saga data instance from inside the event. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* get the saga data by decorating the `IStoreSagaData` implementation with something that copies the saga data to the message context when it is inserted/updated - e.g. something like this:

```
public class SagaDataSnatcher : IStoreSagaData
{
     public SagaDataSnatcher(IStoreSagaData innerSagaPersister) {
         this.innerSagaPersister = innerSagaPersister;
     }

     public void Insert(ISagaData data, string[] sagaDataPropertyPathsToIndex) {
         innerSagaPersister.Insert(data, sagaDataPropertyPathsToIndex);
         SnatchIt(data);
     }

     public void Update(ISagaData data, string[] sagaDataPropertyPathsToIndex) {
         innerSagaPersister.Update(data, sagaDataPropertyPathsToIndex);             
         SnatchIt(data);
     }

     void SnatchIt(ISagaData data) {
         MessageContext.GetCurrent().Items["my-secret-key"] = data;
     }

     // other ISagaData members down here, just delegate to inner
}
```

which I guess could achieve what you're after.

I'm curious though as to what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to implement some kind of idempotence mechanism, storing the messages received with the messages generated as response.